# Proof for hamiltonian cycle in grids having even no. of nodes

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

How can I go about proving that an undirected graph having even no. of nodes (at least one of the rows or columns are even - excluding line graphs of course) have a hamiltonian cycle?

I have managed to come as far as to prove that it is a bipartite graph and (as a result ) has all cycles of even length.

But exactly how can I show that at least one such cycle exists that covers all the available nodes?

Comment: Your question appear to be incomplete. A graph having an even number of nodes is not necessarily hamiltonian.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you have  an $m \times n$ [square grid graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_graph#Square_grid_graph), where, say, $m$ is even.

Hint: induct on $m/2$.